# Run a simple continuous ping and output the results to csv file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, ping

I am trying to run a simple continuous ping on a Windows 10 machine in the cmd window and output the timestamp and response time to two columns in a csv file. I'm not really sure how to do this though as I don't really have any experience with this type of coding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you do not have any code to put into the question and need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done in `batch` language which is equivalent to your request of using cmd. I have put together a simple script bellow that will use the `ping` command along with `findstr` to set the **response time** as a variable.

The script is continuous and can be tweaked from the config at the top of the script with the following settings:

- Address you wish to ping
- Speed between pings
- File name to save as/update

The way the script saves the file is using the `>>` append output to a file command. All in-script context clues are listed in `::` and can be removed from the script if desired. Feel free to edit the script bellow to fit your needs. If you don't know how to turn this script into a batch, copy & paste in notepad, save as `.bat`.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL

::Set the address you wish to ping
SET adress=123.123.12.1

::Set the speed between pings (In seconds)
SET speed=5

::Set the file name to save as - Can include location ex (C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\file.csv)
SET filename=TP.csv

GOTO :ping

:ping
::Ping and extract time= into variable
for /F "tokens=7 delims== " %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %adress%^|findstr /i "time="') do set ping=%%G
echo Current ping for %adress%: %ping%

::Set Time stamp
set curTimestamp=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

::Create file.csv at desired location
echo %curTimestamp%, %ping% >> %filename%

::Wait for x second before next ping
PING localhost -n %speed% >NUL

goto :ping
```

Comment: it should be noted: the string `time=` and the `%currTimeStamp%` calculation have to be adapted to local settings (language and local date format)

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off

::Set the address you wish to ping
set/p host=host Address: 

set logfile=Log_%host%.log

echo Target Host = %host% >%logfile%
::for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>%logfile% && GOTO Ping)

:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 -l 32') do (
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A>>%logfile%
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A
    timeout 1 >NUL 
    GOTO Ping)
```

Comment: this works like a charm and log the time and date properly in the logfile as well just a different variant so thought it will be helpful for some